# How to fetch object file names from a .map file

Tags: scripting, grep, pattern-matching

I need to collect all the names of object files from a .map file, make a list of them and then calculate how much space they are taking in different memory areas. The map files are big (<2500 lines) and doing manually takes a lot of time.
I tried

```
           grep -r '.o' *.map
```

but it gave me a lot of results, that contained 'o'.
This is a sample from the map file,

```
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(start.o)
                              (start)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-main.lib(contiki-main.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(start.o) (main)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-main.lib(contiki-main.o) (ss_dhanush_services_init)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(mio_dma_drv.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init) (MIO_Dma_Init)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(dma_drv.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init) (Dma_Init)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(memory_map.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(mio_dma_drv.o) (Virtual_To_Physical)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(socVer.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init) (System_SOC_VersionInit)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(c_fuction.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init) (memset)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(Rip_api.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(ss_dhanush_init) (ripStartService)
AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(irq_handler.o)
                              AProject/I3/S-SDK/MPU_Asymmetri_ported_Lib_changes_trunk_code/AON/output/contiki-dhanushss.a(mio_dma_drv.o) (register_isr)
```

I just need a list a list of object files in this map file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what do you mean `list of object files`, but give this line a try:

```
 grep -r -Po '[^(]*[.]o(?=[)])' *.map
```

The result is:

```
start.o
contiki-main.o
start.o
contiki-main.o
mio_dma_drv.o
dma_drv.o
memory_map.o
mio_dma_drv.o
socVer.o
c_fuction.o
Rip_api.o
irq_handler.o
mio_dma_drv.o
```